# How to convert dictionary of indices to list of keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

Say you have a dictionary listing the indices where each unique value appear. For example say you alphabet is just `a` and `b` then this dictionary will look something like: `d = {'a': [1, 2, 6], 'b': [3, 7]}`. I would like to convert it to the raw list which shows at the right index the right value, such that in the last example, `l = ['a','a','b',None,None,'a',b']`. I prefer an easy small solution rather than one which has tedious for loops. Thank!

Comment: Why the arbitrary restriction on no for loops? dict and list comprehensions use for loops too! Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: without "for" was just a way to say, quick without long code. Thanks you all for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously doing this without `for` loops is a terrible idea, because the easiest way is (it's not perfect, but it does the job):

```
r = {}
for key, value in d.items():
    for element in value:
        r[element] = key

l = [r.get(i) for i in xrange(1, max(r) + 1)]
```

But if you **REALLY** want to know how to do this without any `for` then have a look:

```
m = {}
i = 0
d_keys = d.keys()
max_value = 0
while i < len(d):
    d_i = d[d_keys[i]]
    j = 0
    while j < len(d_i):
        d_i_j = d_i[j]
        if max_value < d_i_j:
            max_value = d_i_j
        m[d_i_j] = d_keys[i]
        j += 1
    i += 1

l = []
i = 1
while i <= max_value:
    l.append(m.get(i))
    i += 1
```

It's quite easy, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need that, but here is a dirty answer, without loops.

```
d = {'a': [1, 2, 6], 'b': [3, 7]}

map(lambda x: x[0] if x else None, map(lambda x: filter(lambda l: x in d[l], d), range(1, max(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, map(lambda x:d[x], d)))+1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

d.keys()

keys()
Return a copy of the dictionary’s list of keys. See the note for dict.items()

from [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: Are you sure this answers the question?